# align not moving text and scrolling text in same line

Tags: html, marquee

```
<p style="top-align: text-baseline; font-family: Arial Black;font-size: 20px">Green Tips
<marquee direction="left" scrollamount="20" behavior="scroll" style="width: 1500px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial Black;">Green Tips: 1)Turn off lights when leaving a room.                                2)Unplug devices when not in use                            3)Switch to energy efficient appliances                         4)Use led light </marquee>
</p>

image is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwkl7.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/m47AK.png
```

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Could you add more explanation of the problem that you're having? Only with the code and the title I'm having trouble to understand the issue.

Comment: pleas add more explanation for your problem ... the problem is unclear

Comment: i m trying to make the (green tips:) to stay constant and the tips ( 1).....2).....3).....4).....) to scroll to left.